# How to render to a unsigned integer format

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, fbo, render-to-texture

When rendering to an FBO that has an unsigned integer format presumably I can not:

```
gl_FragColour = uvec4(100,100,100,100);
```

as gl_FragColour is a vec4. So presumably I would have to define my own out?

```
out uvec4 colour
```

But will this be interpreted correctly without any other changes?

Also I wanted to use the same shader for both unsigned int formats and normal float textures with a if on a uniform (static branch). I am guessing that would be out of the question (unless I can have 2 outs and only set one?) and I might have to explore a function pointer approach?

Comment: the fragment shader expects the output color to be between 0 and 1 though

Comment: By "function pointer approach", I assume you mean subroutine? That's a Shader Model 5.0 (GL4) feature and it also is not practical for a shader that only has two variations. If you had say 3 different boolean conditions for 6 combinations of behaivor, _then_ subroutines might start to make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So presumably I would have to define my own out?

Yes, absolutely. You ***must*** declare your own fragment data output to write anything other than a floating-point color value.

Mind you, "UNORM" (unsigned normalized) formats like `GL_RGB8` take floating-point color as their input even though they are fixed-point data types. The real oddballs are actually the new INT/UINT formats introduced in OpenGL 3.0; they do not have floating-point to integer conversions defined and thus can only be written to using integer colors.

> But will this be interpreted correctly without any other changes?

Traditionally what happens is that the value gets *clamped* to the range [**0.0**,**1.0**] and then since 99% of the time the output color format is unsigned normalized, each component is re-scaled to the fixed-point range (*e.g.* if `GL_RGB8` => (float_color * **255**)).

If you have a floating-point or integer color buffer the clamping and scaling behavior no longer applies, but of course writing a floating-point color to an integer color buffer is undefined as discussed earlier. This is why when integral color formats (signed and unsigned integer) were introduced to core GL, `gl_FragColor` became deprecated (GL 3.0).

> Also I wanted to use the same shader for both unsigned int formats and normal float textures with a if on a uniform (static branch). I am guessing that would be out of the question (unless I can have 2 outs and only set one?) and I might have to explore a function pointer approach?

Actually, this ***is*** doable. But it would require you to use two different FBO image attachment locations.

#### Imagine the following shader:

```
#version 330

uniform bool is_float;

layout(location = 0) out vec4  frag_color_float;
layout(location = 1) out uvec4 frag_color_uint;

void main (void) {
  if (is_float)
    frag_color_float = vec4 (0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
  else
    frag_color_uint  = uvec4 (1,2,3,0xff);
}
```

In the above scenario, you would attach a traditional floating-point or fixed-point color buffer (`GL_RGBA32F` or `GL_RGBA8`) to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and an unsigned integer color buffer (`GL_RGBA32UI`) to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`.

I do not know how practical this approach is in the long-run, but it is possible.

Comment: I should point out that if you do not write to an output from a fragment shader, then the value of that output is undefined... so in theory the implementation is free to write anything it wants or nothing at all to the output that _*you*_ did not write to. _"If subsequent fixed functionality consumes fragment data and an execution of a fragment shader executable does not write a value to it, then the fragment data consumed is undefined."_ (effectively states that things like blending will have undefined results for the branch not taken).

Answer (score 4):

[gl_FragColor](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Predefined_Variables_By_Version) is deprecated since GLSL 130. Since then, you can define any output for a fragment shader you want and especially also in uvec4 format:

```
layout(location = 0) out uvec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = uvec4(100,100,100,100);
}
```

If the framebuffer has an unsigned integer format, this should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the fragment shader is always automatically rescaled from `0.0-1.0` to the range that fits in the FBO. So there is no need to change how you output in the shader.